# Generate INFORMATION_SCHEMA table for MySQL database

Tags: mysql, information-schema

I'm using an old version of MySQL (4.0) on an old server and for some reason it has no INFORMATION_SCHEMA database,
I don't know if this version of MySQL did not include INFORMATION_SCHEMA or if someone deleted it.

Is there some way to (re)Generate this database?

thanks

```
# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 12.22 Distrib 4.0.18, for suse-linux (x86_64)
```

Comment: It's not available for 4.x versions, you need MySQL 5.0 or higher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` database was added in MySQL 5.02. It's not possible to create or delete it. It's managed by the server directly. Instead of trying to find a way to work around this, your time would be much better spent upgrading the server if at all possible :)

Comment: Thanks, and I wish I could! All "upgrade" resources are unfortunately being spent on migrating to Microsoft SQL 2008 :( sad day....

Comment: Sorry to hear that ActionOwl. Hopefully you can manage to have some time allocated for the upgrade. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you are out of luck. `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` was not added until MySQL 5.0.