# 'information_schema.character_sets' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I have installed WAMP server2.2 . Installation completed smoothly. but when i tried to access phpmyadmin. It gives error. I changed the password from /wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.5.1/conf.inc.php.

But now I am facing another error as follows:

Error:-

```
SQL query: Documentation Edit

SELECT * FROM information_schema.CHARACTER_SETS

MySQL said: Documentation
#1146 - Table 'information_schema.character_sets' doesn't exist
```

I am new to this so please help me out....I stuck on the same error......

I can't proceed further without phpmyadmin..... Hope somebody help me as early as possible to resolve this error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What information do you need?

Comment: When I am accessing phpmyadmin.... It gives me above error. I can't access phpmyadmin. Can you tell me how to resolve this error??

Comment: Did you change the password to the mysql 'root' userid or just change the password used in the /wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.5.1/conf.inc.php.  If you just change the $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = ''; to contain a value then just remove your change and you will get back into phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1):

Login via command line,

```
mysql -h myhost -u myusername -p

<ENTER PASSWORD>
```

run the command

```
show databases;
```

sample output:

```
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| mysql              |
| phprojekt          |
| test               |
+--------------------+
```

if  there is no database information_schema in your output , your mysql server is too old. (Version 4.x, most recent is 5.6 as of 2013). This can be the case, if you try to connect to an old database server in your company which didn't bother to upgrade (happens quite often for many reasons).

Also read this:
[Generate INFORMATION_SCHEMA table for MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325773/generate-information-schema-table-for-mysql-database)
(you can't)